# Maintaining serial port opened in Python using Powershell

Tags: python, powershell

I am trying to connect Novatel Propak6 receiver to ground station through RS 232. (For GPS denied environment)

I was able to connect the receiver to take commands through powershell, but I want to use python to integrate it with other sensors that operates separately from it.

I wrote following python code using pyserial, but unlike powershell, it is not accepting commands:

```
import serial

s = serial.Serial(port="COM1", baudrate=115200)

if (s.isOpen()):
    s.write(b'CONNECTIMU COM3 IMU_ADIS16488')
    s.close()
```

The command CONNECTIMU should activate connection between IMU and the receiver, but unlike powershell, this is not responsding.

So instead I tried using subprocess and os.system to execute powershell through python, but both of them return this error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $port.open()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

These are the codes I am using to run powershell through python:

```
os.system('powershell.exe [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames()')
time.sleep(1)
os.system('powershell.exe "$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM1, 115200, None, 8, one"')
time.sleep(1)
os.system('powershell.exe $port.open()')
os.system('powershell.exe $port.WriteLine("CONNECTIMU COM3 IMU_ADIS16488")')
time.sleep(1)
```

```
init_port=subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM1, 115200, None, 8, one"])
port_open = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "$port.open()"])
imu_connect = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "$port.WriteLine('CONNECTIMU COM3 IMU_ADIS16488)"])
init_port.communicate()
port_open.communicate()
imu_connect.communicate()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a line feed at the end of the command:

```py
s.write(b'CONNECTIMU COM3 IMU_ADIS16488\n')
```

or

```py
cmd = 'CONNECTIMU COM3 IMU_ADIS16488\n'
s.write(cmd.encode("ascii"))
```

You can also change the timeout and maybe the number of stop bits.

```py
s = serial.Serial(port="COM1", 
                  baudrate=115200, 
                  timeout=1,
                  stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
```

Comment: You’re welcome. May I ask you to check my answer as accepted (check mark on the top left of the answer)? Thank you in advance.